Linearization of long wave radiation equation
I am basing my reduced order building model on the equations proposed in the article “A methodology for generating reduced-order models for large-scale buildings using the Krylov subspace method” https://doi.org/10.1080/19401493.2020.1752309.
I am having trouble understanding the proposed linear model.


In this snapshot I include the proposed linearization for the longwave radiation equations. It uses T1 (the linearized variable) to calculate the median of the sky/ground temperatures. I do not understand how that is considered linear, when they are using T1 to calculate that variable and then are cubing it. That would not be linear, right?
Could anyone please provide a clarification on this aspect?
